# How to find these vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra

The theorem 8.55 in *Linear Algebra Done Right, Sheldon Axler, 3rd Edition* says:

> Suppose $N\in \mathcal{L}(V)$ is nilpotent. Then there exist vectors $v_1,\dots,v_n\in V$ and nonnegative integers $m_1,\dots,m_n$ such that
>
> (a) $N^{m_1}v_1,\dots,Nv_1,\dots,N^{m_n}v_n,\dots,Nv_n,v_n$ is a basis of $V$;
>
> (b) $N^{m_1+1}v_1=\dotsb=N^{m_n+1}v_n=0.$

My question is: how to find $v_1,\dots,v_n$?

Comment: How did you define nilpotent?

Comment: @Meowdog There exists a nonnegative integer $k$ such that $N^k=0$.

Comment: Okay. To be honest, I think that proving by contradiction might be easier.

Comment: @Meowdog Thank you. Proof of this theorem is listed on that book, and I have totally understood this. What I am wondering is how to find $v_1,\dots,v_n$, where the theorem only shows the existence of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sketch**: compute ranks of $N^k$, when it drops find elements that span $N^k(V)$ along with $N^{k + 1}(V)$, then take preimages under $N^k$.

Comment: Brilliant result!